# Cleveref not compressing equation refs with subequations

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, cref

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[
    reprint,
    nofootinbib,
    amsmath,
    floatfix,
    superscriptaddress,
    longbibliography
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1 \label{eq:1}
        \end{align}
        \begin{align}
            2 \label{eq:2}
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            3 \label{eq:3}
        \end{align}
        \begin{align}
            4 \label{eq:4}
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \begin{align}\label{eq:5}
        5
    \end{align}

    \Cref{eq:1,eq:2,eq:3,eq:4,eq:5}

\end{document}
```

This compiles to

> Equations (1a), (1b), (2a), (2b) and (3)

How can I get cleveref to compress this to (1a)--(3) since all inbetween labels are present?

Comment: In this case, you want `\Crefrange{eq:1}{eq:5}`.

Comment: @gusbrs I suspect the question is how to get `cleveref` to do this without explicitly requesting it i.e. the way it would handle, say, `\cref{sec:1,sec:2,sec:3}`. Perhaps the OP could edit to clarify?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, I was looking for a way to use `\cref{sec:1,sec:2,sec:3}`, as @cfr mentioned. If for some reason an equation will be inserted between the other ones, it should not be included.

Comment: `cleveref` treats equation 3 as different in kind from equations 1a through 2b, so I don't think you can make it treat all 5 as compressible because 3 is part of a different group. To change this, the easiest way would probably be to force `cleveref` to treat them as all of a kind, but I don't know what side-effects that would have. I gather support for `subequations` is handled specially. In light of the history of changes, this is probably a response to problems/bugs. I'm not sure about any of this, mind. I'm just guessing.

Comment: For the subequations themselves, `cleveref` appears to treat the equations in each `subequations` environment separately. So if you add a third to the first group, you do get automatic compression: `(1a) to (1c), (2a), (2b) and (3)` for example. This *seems* to be by design, but I'm not sure what the thinking here is.

Comment: @cfr I know that. ;) (I cannot ping two, but Herp is meant too). But the thing is fact that "all inbetween labels are present" is not really of much consequence, `cleveref` does not even track the sequence of the labels. It works with the printed representation, and it would not compress something into a range that would become ambiguous. It would compress 1a,1b,1c into one, but not even 1a,1b,2a. `zref-clever` can get you a little further with something like `\zcref[range]{eq:1,eq:2,eq:3,eq:4,eq:5}`. But you still have to say you want a range, no escape there.

Comment: ... In other words, my comment meant to say `\crefrange` is the best you can get.